# Enqueue Different Stylesheet in wordpress depending on user input via meta box

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am creating a wordpress plugin from which user can select different styles from the plugin options panel. I want to enqueue css file via `wp_enqueue_style()` according to the user input.

I am getting error when I want to get the metabox value inside the plugins php file.

Error Says:

```
Calling undefined variable $... on line no ..."
```

Is there any way I can get the value of the metabox inside php file and enqueue the appropiate css file according to the user input on dashboard.

I am using [Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress) plugin to retrieve user input from plugin option panel for this purpose

My code:

```
function easyloader_theme() {
    global $post;
    $theme = easyloader_get_option( 'easyloader_theme' );

    wp_register_style('easyloader_style', plugins_url('themes/pace-theme-'. $theme .'.css',__FILE__),'','1.0.0.', false);
    wp_enqueue_style('easyloader_style');
}
add_action( 'init', 'easyloader_theme');
```

I can easily get value of this user input in any when I paste this code in themes php file like (header.php, page.php, footer.php ) via

```
<?php global $post; $theme = easyloader_get_option( 'easyloader_theme' ); echo $theme; ?>
```

I just want to get the value inside my plugin php file not in the theme file.

Comment: There is not enough information? Show us the code you have attempt. How do we know how you are trying to retrieve metabox value.

Comment: Questioner has updated the question; no need to close it.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to enqueue is with the following action:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'easyloader_theme' );
function easyloader_theme() { 
    /* Enqueue Scripts AND Styles */ 
}
```

Looks like the plugin has some internal cache, but at the end you can try using WP function directly:

```
get_option( 'easyloader_theme' );
```